# Bluetooth with Windows Mobile 6 device emulator

Tags: c#, windows-7, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

Is there a way I can connect to my Bluetooth dongle from my device emulator?
I am using Windows 7 and unfortunately I could not use the [FreeBT USB Driver](http://code.google.com/p/bthmsdevemul/downloads/detail?name=FreeBT%20USB%20Driver.zip&can=2&q=) as I couldn't install the driver.

Comment: What software is your emulator running? Visual Studio? If I remember correctly (IIRC), VS does not have a Bluetooth feature built into any of its emulators. So, No you can't.

Comment: @jp2code Yes, I am using VS2008. Do you know another emulator that supports BT?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I only develop in Visual Studio, so I know their emulator does NOT have Bluetooth support.